# Spring Controller Test using actual data during bean validation

Tags: spring, database, validation, testing, mockito

I have a controller method for creating a user like below.

```
@Secured({RoleNames.ADMIN})
@PostMapping(value = "/users/create")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody CreateUserCommand command) {
    UserDto userDto = userService.create(command);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userDto);
}
```

I need to validate CreateUserCommand (with holds form data come from front-end). For example whether email already exists in database.

I created a validator like below:

```
public class UserEmailExistsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserEmailExists, CreateUserCommand> {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

public UserEmailExistsValidator(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(CreateUserCommand command, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    UserDto userDto = userService.getByEmail(command.getEmail());
    return userDto == null;
}
}
```

My problem is that: when I try to run Controller Test for this "users/create" endpoint, it checks actual database (not test database) whether e-mail exists that user. So if that user e-mail exists in database, validations fail and therefore tests are failing.

**EDIT**

This is my Controller Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ApplicationMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private Principal principal;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(principal.getName()).thenReturn("user");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSaveUser_withValidRequestBody() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = getMockMvcWithAuthorities(RoleNames.ADMIN);

        mockMvc.perform(
                post(RestEndPoint.BASE_URL + "/users/create")
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .content(new JSONObject()
                                .put("username", "John Doe")
                                .put("email", "test@test.com")
                                .put("gender", "M")
                                .toString())
        )
        /* MockMvc.perform is failing (Returns status 400) due to validator class returns false... */
        ........
    }
}


@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@WebMvcTest
public @interface ApplicationMvcTest {
    @AliasFor("controllers")
    Class<?>[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor("value")
    Class<?>[] controllers() default {};

    boolean useDefaultFilters() default true;

    ComponentScan.Filter[] includeFilters() default {};

    ComponentScan.Filter[] excludeFilters() default {};

    @AliasFor(
            annotation = AutoConfigureMockMvc.class,
            attribute = "secure"
    )
//            Change default to false
            boolean secure() default false;

    @AliasFor(
            annotation = ImportAutoConfiguration.class,
            attribute = "exclude"
    )
    Class<?>[] excludeAutoConfiguration() default {};
}
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.8, Mockito3.0.0.

Comment: show the test class how you have configured.

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran, I have added my test classes.

Comment: have you configured any embedded database like H2 for testing? If not you should do

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to go to the database then where ever you are interacting with the database that class has to be mocked. So if you are using a repository then you have to mock that and let it return the expected value. If it is `UserService` then mock that and when a call to find the email is called then return the value.

```
when(userService.getByEmail(anyString())).thenReturn(null);
```